# How to increase allowed number of clients in Redis?

Tags: systemd, redis

(Server: Ubuntu Xenial 64bit)

**/etc/security/limits.conf** has the following lines:

```
*                soft    nofile          24576
*                hard    nofile          32768
redis            soft    nofile          24576
redis            hard    nofile          32768
```

I have configured the user limits for the `redis` user:

```
redis@myserver:~$ ulimit -n
24576
```

**/etc/redis/redis.conf** has the following line:

```
maxclients 24000
```

Yet, when I grab the `maxclients` configuration parameter I am still getting the unexpected value:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> config get maxclients
1) "maxclients"
2) "4064"
```

Could someone please explain to me what is going on here??

Answer (score 3):

After a chat to the guys on irc://irc.freenode.net/redis I modified the **/etc/systemd/system/redis.service**, added the following line to it:

```
LimitNOFILE=48000
```

and it all started working! So, looks like changing the limits in /etc/security/limits.conf does not help.

After `systemctl restart redis-server` I got the expected:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> config get maxclients
1) "maxclients"
2) "24000"
```